# Error: Apollo Server requires either an existing schema, modules or typeDefs

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, apollo, apollo-server

I have this function that I want to test, ina nodeJS project that uses Apollo Server's federated gateway implementation.

```
@Service()
export class Server {


    constructor();
    }

    async startAsync(): Promise<void> {
        await this.createApolloGateway();
    }

    private async createApolloGateway(): Promise<void> {

        const gateway = new ApolloGateway({
                serviceList: [{ name: 'products', url: 'https://products-service.dev/graphql' },
                { name: 'reviews', url: 'https://reviews-service.dev/graphql' }]});


        const {schema, executor} = await gateway.load();
        const server = new ApolloServer({schema, executor});

        return new Promise((resolve, _) => {
            server.listen(8080).then(({url}) => {
                resolve();
            });
        });
    }

}
```

but when I test this function I have this error:

```
Error: Apollo Server requires either an existing schema, modules or typeDefs
```

I have tride to mock the schema doing this in jest framework

```
 apolloGateway = createMockInstance(ApolloGateway);

 it('should start an http server', async () => {
        // Arrange

        const server = new Server(configurationService, loggerService);

        const schema = `
  type User {
    id: ID!
    name: String
    lists: [List]
  }

  type RootQuery {
    user(id: ID): User
  }
  schema {
    query: RootQuery
  }
`;

         apolloGateway.load = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(schema);




        // Act
        await server.startAsync();

        // Assert
        await expect(server).not.toBeNull;
    }, 30000);
```

but I have the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the apollo-server to least version and pass only gateway when create apollo server.

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  gateway  
});
```